# PHP passing boolean to ArrayObject for inner comparison

Tags: php, dataframe

Is there a way to access the details of a boolean passed to an ArrayObject for comparison with each element of an array?

I've begun work on a dataframe for PHP and seem to have hit a glass ceiling with this one.

Sample code:

```
<?php

class DataFrame extends ArrayObject {
    public function offsetGet($key) {
        if (is_bool($key)) {
            echo "Passed a boolean: {$key}\n";
        } else {
            echo "Comparing: {$key}\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Just a simple case with the code:

```
$df = new DataFrame();
$df['hello'] = 'world';
$df[$df['hello'] == 'world'];
```

will output (for any non-null, non-false, non-zero comparison):

```
Comparing: hello
Passed a boolean:
```

otherwise:

```
Comparing: hello
Passed a boolean: 1
```

Either way I have no access to the comparison with this approach.

---

Is there an interface I can implement in order to gain access to boolean comparison methods or is something like this out of reach of PHP? Either way this is just sugar for a number of other approaches that can be taken, it would just be a shame to not have classic dataframe syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean R-like dataframe syntax, I am sorry to say that PHP does not expose such interface natively, but nothing prevents you from implementing it.

The closest you'll get from this is with the [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter) function.

For PHP 5.3+ you can do:

```
$data = array('hello', 'world');
$selected = array_filter($data, function($val) {
    return $val === 'world';
});
var_dump($selected); // will output: array(1) { 0 => world }
```